# How to create single exe with a pygubu UI file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a UI file created from pygubu using tkinter. I need to create a single executable file that packs everything together.

I've tried to use pyinstaller -F, but the result file is still looking for the UI file. I've looked at pyuic, but it doesn't look, to me, like it will work with a pygubu UI file. Additionally, I can't seem to get it to install.

Everything runs cleanly as a python script, it's just when I try to package it into an exe.

Errors from running the exe after creation are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Helper.py", line 365 in <module>
  File "Helper.py", line 333, in __init__
  File "site-packages\pygubu\builder\__init__.py, line 280, in add_from_file
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Helper.ui'
[1756] Failed to execute script Helper
```

I don't want to have to redesign the UI in another tool, but I will if necessary. I just need that single exe file for distribution to our less tech minded staff.

Comment: I used `cx_Freeze` to compile my code into an exe. You can try that.

Comment: Use `--add-data` to include required file with pyinstaller.  It can be used multiple times to include multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--add-data` or the .spec file to tell pyinstaller what to include.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

Comment: Quite short but a decent answer. I recommend to take the [tour] and read [answer], if you want to improve it even more.